# Entity Framework .Any does not generate expected SQL WHERE clause

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Entity Framework and Linq-To-Entities are really giving me some headaches. I have a fairly simple query:

```
var result = feed.FeedItems.Any(ei => ei.ServerId == "12345");
```

feed is a single EF entity I selected earlier in a separate query from the same context.

But the generated SQL just throws away the .Any condition and requests all FeedItems of the feed object which can be several thousands of records which is a waste of Network bandwith. Seems the actual .Any comparison is done in C#:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[FeedId], [t0].[ServerId], [t0].[Published], [t0].[Inserted], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Content], [t0].[Author], [t0].[WebUri], [t0].[CommentsUri]
FROM [dbo].[FeedItem] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[FeedId] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=3
```

I also tried:

```
!feed.FeedItems.Where(ei => ei.ServerId == "12345").Any();
```

But it doesn't change anything. Even removing Any() and querying for the complete list of items does not change the query.

I don't get it ... why isn't this working as I would expect? There should be a

```
WHERE ServerId == 1234
```

clause in the SQL statement.

Thanks very much for any help/clarification :)

Comment: What is `feed.FeedItems`?

Comment: As mentioned, feed is queried from the DbContext before so feed.FeedItems is an EntitySet<FeedItem>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nicholas already noticed, looks like query executed in `FeedItems` property (possibly you are returning `List` or `IEnumerable`) and whole list of items are returned from database. After that you are applying `Any` to in-memory collection. That's why you don't see `WHERE ServerId == 1234` in SQL query.

When you apply `Any` to `IQueryable` generated query will look like:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            [dbo].[FeedItem] AS [t0]
            WHERE [t0].[ServerId] = @p0
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END) AS [value]
```

Comment: Now I get the feed object from the DB Context like this:

Feed feed = db.Feeds.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == feedId);

So feed.FeedItems would by an EntitySet<FeedItem> ... so that should normally work, should it?

Comment: Oh nevermind ... EntitySet isn't IQueryable ... damn, that was a wrong assumption by me. Thanks very much for your fast response!